# What is the difference between defining the iteration variable within a "for" statement vs. before it?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want to know what the difference is between defining an iteration variable before (outside) the `for` statement that uses it, as below...

```
    int i;
    for(i=1;...)
```

...Against defining the variable within the `for` statement, as below:

```
    for(int i=1;...)
```

Comment: In second case you can't access `i` outside for loop

Comment: but in first one you can access outside or after `for` loop. Means both have different scopes

Comment: Understood the difference.TY everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is actually very simple. `int i; for (i = 1; )` and 
`for (int i = 1; )`. The difference between the two is that one declares `i` outside of the `for` loop while the other declares `i` on the inside. Either way is completely fine and will result in the same amount of loops in the program. I hope this helps.

Edit: I should also mention that if you declare `i` inside of the `for` loop, it will not be accessible outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

They have different scope

pre-declaration, you can access `i` outside the for loop

```
int i;
for(i=1;...)
 {
    // i accessible here
 }
 // i accessible here
i = 10; // will work and update i outside for loop
```

inline declaration, this case you only can access the `i` inside the for loop

```
 for(int i=1;...)
  {
     // i accessible here
  }
   // but not accessible here
 i = 10; // won't work outside for loop
```

Comment: There has got to be some difference my teacher told me there's a difference are you sure there is no difference at all between these two except the pre-declaration and inline declaration?

Comment: @user3607864 see my update hope will help

Answer (score 0):

Likely the most significant difference is scope: in the first example. local variables like your `i` are visible inside the block they are defined. So in your first example, `i` will continue to exist (and have its then current value) after the `for` loop, while in the second case, it will be valid only in the `for` loop and loop body.

Answer (score 0):

The diffence is in the variable scope. When you declare a variable outside of the for-loop (like in your first example) it will be accessible in the loop and outside of the loop.

```
int i;
for(i=1; i<100; i++)
{ 
    // do great things
}

i = 10000; // Works fine
```

When you declare it in the loop declaration, it won't be accessible outside of the loop.

```
for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
{ 
    // do great things
}

i = 10000; // Won't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies within the scope of variable i. In first case let's say your code is:

```
void SomeFunction(){
    int i;
    for(..){
        .. 
        // i is available here
    }
    // And here too
}
```

While in second case it's only available inside the loop block{}. Outside, it'll give error.

```
 void SomeFunction(){
    for(int i;..){
        .. 
        // i is available here
    }
    // But not here
}
```